# form action change javascript by user option selection

Tags: javascript

I want to give user to select option to visit his website, i have following code, can anyone help me to correct it;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSubmitForm() {
      document.selectDisplay.action = document.getElementById("selectwebiste").value;
      return true;
    }
</script>

<form method="get" id="uesfulwebsite">
    <select id="selectwebiste">
        <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
        <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
        <option value="http://www.facebook.com">facebook</option>
        <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Over Flow</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

Comment: Don't be afraid to make your code more readable by indenting it properly. Also, what's the problem with the code? Why you think it needs to be "corrected"?

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful problem description. What is that is not working? What do you expect the code to do and what does it do?

Comment: after submit the form, action remain on same page, not opening option value page...

Comment: What are you trying to do with `document.selectDisplay.action`? There is no element with the name or ID `selectDisplay`. Also, `onSubmitForm` is never called. I recommend to learn the basics about event handling and the DOM first before you advance further: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html, http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Comment: problem solve, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Form needs event onsubmit="onSubmitForm();

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onSubmitForm() 
{
    document.forms[0].action = document.getElementById("selectwebiste").value;

    return true;
}
</script>

<form method="get" id="uesfulwebsite" onsubmit="onSubmitForm();">
<select id="selectwebiste">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="http://www.facebook.com">facebook</option>
    <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Over Flow</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"  value="Go!" />
```

Comment: {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: Are you using JsFiddle.net ? Code is working on localhost

Comment: problem solve bro.. thanks

Comment: Dont say thanks , please upvote and click the check button if u accept the solution :)